# Is it possible to add two or more repository controls in devepxress grid control

Tags: winforms, devexpress

Hey i am dealing with winform(c#) application. i am using Devexpress Grid Control.

Is it possible to have two or more repository controls in grid control column for edit purpose.

eg.. say like a textbox and combo box in **a grid column**.(this is possible in web application by adding item templates to the grid column)

Is this possible or any other way to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the GridColumn.ColumnEdit property to specifying the editor used to edit a column's value

Comment: Yes that is true but i want two or more editor in a column. As you suggested their would be only one control in the column.

Comment: I think that you could make a custom control with more editors by inheriting from RepositoryItemPopupBase and then add that control as ColumnEdit